# Getting a coordinate on a panned canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, coordinates

I have a `Canvas` inside a `UserControl` that can be panned around. I want to be able to know what's the upper left corner coordinate of the UserControl relative to the upper left corner of the Canvas each time the user pans the canvas around so that I can update another usercontrol with that info.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the offset of the `Canvas` control within the `UserControl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can achieve what you want by using the [`TransformToAncestor(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608865.aspx) method. This will give you a transform that you can use to acquire the offset. As far as I understand it, if you retrieve the transform from the `Canvas` to the `UserControl` then apply that to a position of (0, 0), then you should get your offset.

So the code should look something like:

```
GeneralTransform transform = canvas.TransformToAncestor(this);
Point offset = transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Where `canvas` is your `Canvas` control and `this` is your `UserControl`.

Refer to the linked MSDN documentation for more information.

Comment: Great, that's what I wanted. Thanks Slade!